# Academically sound resources about "The Dane Wall"

Tags: discussion

I am looking for academically-sound, accessible online resources about the influence of Old Danish on Old English in a region somewhere between northern and southern England. It was referred to as "The Dane Wall".

I have heard the process described as the intentional simplification of Old English grammatical features under the influence of Old Danish.

It precedes the influence of Norman French on Old English described in Nist's "A Structural history of English".

Comment: I've never heard of the Dane Wall. Are you thinking of the 'Danelaw', the region influenced by Viking civilisation, roughly north and east of a diagonal line across England?

Comment: It's true we don't do resource requests, but if you had a specific question about the influence of Old Danish on Old English, that would be OK. You can edit this question if you like or ask a new one.

Comment: @KateBunting: I'm sure you mean "influenced by the Norse civilisation".

Comment: So far as I can make out, [Danevirke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danevirke) is aka "The Dane Wall". But it's not in Britain anyway - according to Wikipedia it's *a system of Danish fortifications in Schleswig-Holstein, Germany ... last used for military purposes in 1864*.

Comment: Wikipedia is a short academically questionable intro to many subjects with links to reputable ones. You should start there with [Danelaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danelaw)